# Ordenando CSS con Brackets

Tags: css

Como ordenar las propiedades en orden alfabético del CSS usando el editor Brackets, sin necesidad de usar una página web para ello.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un plugin para brackets que ordena e identa tus clases css se llama CSScomb y puedes encontrar el plugin en: http://csscomb.com/. Te adjunto información de instalación y uso

**Uso**

Seleccioan el css a ordenar y presiona las teclas Ctrl + Shift + C o selecciona 
Edit > Sort with CSScomb en el menú.

**Instalación**

File > Extension Manager > Install from URL: Pega la dirección https://github.com/i-akhmadullin/brackets-csscomb en el campo URL